# Process Builder: How to use custom label/translated text in custom notification body?

Tags: process-builder

We are trying to send a custom notification message to the owner of a custom object record using process builder.
The body of the notification must be translated depending on the record owner language which can be either French / English / German / Dutch.

[image]

Within the notification body section, no menu is available to use a custom label (we can only choose merged field from the target record object, refer to image).
I have tried using custom label in the notification body field as follows:

**Option 1**

```
{!$Label.myCustomLabel}
```

**Option 2**

```
$Label.myCustomLabel
```

I was allowed to save both above options and activate the process builder.
But none of the options worked after testing, the text is actually rendered as-is and is not displaying the translated value of the custom label.

**Option 3:**

Created a new formula field on the custom object which actually referenced the custom label as value. Used this field as merged field on the notification body. Now this option displays the text of the label, but it is not translated based on the language of the record owner who receives the notification.

Note: cannot add different criteria nodes in the process builder to check each 4 possible languages of the owner and set a hard coded message in the body, because cannot access owner language field in process builder criteria to check owner language value

Any idea how to render translated text in custom notification based on record owner?

Comment: I see this post where they use a PB formula, and reference the system variable that way.  Haven't tested w notification builder but presume it should work https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iqabQAA

Comment: Custom notification action is different from other types of PB actions, we dont have a menu to select system variable, there's only merged field from the object. for reference, i have added a screenshot in my question. already tried to "hack" the notification body with $Label.MyLabel but it didnt work

Comment: Ahh.  Have you tried creating the notification and then using translation workbench?  I know flows can be translated using that, and pb is just a flow under the hood.  So maybe it's possible that way?

Comment: unfortunately, translation workbench does not allow to translate text in notification body

Comment: You may be left with submitting an idea...but you could also try posting in tbe workflow automation group in success.

Comment: Any other option you have got in between. I was having a similar requirement

Comment: @EagerinSf We did not use process builder in the end, as workaround you can use apex to send the custom notification and use a custom label for the body text, check apex guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Messaging_CustomNotification.htm)